# Why base.method() does not calling base class method in C#?

Tags: c#, stream, networkstream

i have a class Named `TCPStream`. it inherits `NetworkStream` class. 
And `NetworkStream` inherits `Stream` Class i.e.,

```
public class TCPStream : NetworkStream, IComparable<TCPStream>
{...}
```

And

```
public class NetworkStream : Stream
{...}
```

Now, `Stream` Class have a Function `ReadAsync(,,,)`, and this function also overrided in `TCPStream` Class.

**My problem is: When i call `base.ReadAsync(,,,)` in the `TCPStream` class, it executes itself Again and Again...( NOT Calling (Parent) `Stream` class method...)**

Therefor, `StackOverFlowException` occurs due to self-calling..

What should I do to achieve this task?
Code Snippet is Below

```
 public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {

            // int read_RetryCount = 0;
            // repeat till Complete Packet Received
            TimeSpan timeOutLimit = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            if (CanTimeout)
                timeOutLimit = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ReadTimeout);     // maxTimeOutLimit


                **// *** Here is Problem, base.ReadAsync(,,,) Not execute Parent's ReasAsync(,,,)***
                // *** After This Line, Function Execute itself Again..*****

                var length = base.ReadAsync(_localBuffer.Array, _localBuffer.Offset, _localBuffer.Count ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                Console.WriteLine("Total Bytes read = " + length);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't spam with unrelated tags. For future questions please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without the code of the overriding method it´s impossibelt o guess what your problem is. So please show the coe of `TCPStream.ReadAsync`.

Comment: If you have a method within a class that is meant to call the method in the parent class then you will have to state `base.Method()` explicitly.  If the method is overridden in your subclass and you have an instance of the subclass, then that method will always be called - that's what overriding means.

Comment: @HimBromBeere due to the complexities of the `Stream` class, I would expect to need to see more than just that method...

Comment: @HimBromBeere  i've updated my post , with adding code snippets.. please take a review

Comment: @FahadUsman it is very unclear to me why a *single* call to `ReadAsync` in your code actually loops forever until the end of the stream; that sounds very wrong - you might want to look into that.

Comment: @FahadUsman additional small note: I see you have a `size <= 0` check - if I assume that you are actually checking `count` here (`size` isn't defined), then please note that a zero-length read is actually "a thing": it is a very useful pattern that can be used to say "call me when you have something" - passing in either a shared empty buffer, or just any part of a pooled buffer (since we're reading zero bytes, it doesn't actually matter). This is a very useful trick in high load scenarios. My point: you should change that to `< 0`. A zero-length read is a legit and permitted thing.

Comment: Respected @MarcGravell .... Actually, there will come **Thousands of connection**  to Communicate.., And i'll handle all the other problems Like, use Async/Await, Loops etc.,   But My Original Problem is "Not calling Parent Class Method"... and There is no Problem With  **Parameters**... i've tried it..

But **ReadAsync(,,,,)** calling Again itself Continuously..

Comment: @FahadUsman when you have thousands of connections is **exactly when** the zero-length read is especially important and useful. You're not using that trick right now: that's fine - nobody is forcing you to. But a zero-length isn't invalid, is the point.

Comment: @MarcGravell For simplicity, i've removed unnecessary Code... But Original Problem Remains Left...

Comment: @FahadUsman you say "original problem remains left": have you *added the `cancellationToken` to your `base` call*, as has been suggested?

Comment: Yes,,,, i'd Tried...   But it was Useless

Comment: @FahadUsman no, it isn't useless - here it is working perfectly: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/aadc5bb2b53d7a803b606629518de532 (and : writing a complete TCP client+server to show this is going "above and beyond"). So whatever the problem is *now*: you haven't told us. Adding the `cancellationToken` to the call fixes the problem you reported.

Comment: @FahadUsman and here it is with the `async` implementation - an important change, and again: working perfectly: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/23a584fac539057c451e6d026c7c7a87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've added the code, the problem is clear:

You have:

```
public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
     var length = base.ReadAsync(_localBuffer.Array,
         _localBuffer.Offset, _localBuffer.Count ).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
}
```

Now look at the default implementation of `ReadAsync(byte[],int,int)`:

```
public Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => 
    this.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, CancellationToken.None);
```

You didn't call the same method that you're overriding - you called a very subtly different one. 
The problem is that you didn't pass along the cancellation token. If you simply change to:

```
 var length = base.ReadAsync(_localBuffer.Array,
     _localBuffer.Offset, _localBuffer.Count, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

It should go away.

Note however that you should never use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` like this. A better solution would be to add the `async` modifier to your method, and use:

```
 var length = await base.ReadAsync(_localBuffer.Array,
     _localBuffer.Offset, _localBuffer.Count, cancellationToken);
```

Alternatively, lose the `while(true)` loop - it looks very wrong - and *don't* add the `async` modifier, and just:

```
return base.ReadAsync(_localBuffer.Array,
     _localBuffer.Offset, _localBuffer.Count, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Dear Marc ? Why we cannot call another method of parent class? using base.someAnotherMethod()?? and ReadAsync() withOut cancellationToken is also a method in Parent class

Comment: @FahadUsman *it is* indeed a method, but it is a **convenience method** for *the external caller*, not for you as a `Stream` implementer - and what it does is: call the current `ReadAsync(byte[],int,int,CancellationToken)` method (i.e your method) with a default cancellation token.

Comment: @HimBromBeere all of which is already discussed in here... just sayin'

Comment: Dear @MarcGravell ...  if you've noticed that , My Function has Also 4 parameters,.. and if i passed 3 params while calling, then
WHY my Function execute itself...?????  and WHY it is not give Error Like MisMatch parameters etc...

Comment: @FahadUsman No, when writing `base.ReadAsnyc`, you only provide **three** parameters. Thus the non virtual method from `Stream` is called, which itself calls the *virtual* one with **four** arguments. This is **overridden** in your case.

Comment: @FahadUsman I literally showed you the code for why that happens, and explained it in words twice, but I'll say it again: the 3 parameter version **calls the 4 parameter version**. That is what it does - it is the *only* thing that it does. Your method is the 4 parameter version, so if your 4 parameter version calls the base 3 parameter version: you are calling yourself. The 3 parameter version isn't "call the 4 parameter version at my current level" - it is "call the virtual method of the 4 parameter version", i.e. call the **top** method: yours

Comment: Ohh Yeah..!!  That's it...
Thanks To All... But specially Thanks to @MarcGravell , there was number of  parameters issue, But Now Every Thing is Fine... Thanks Again..